# Handling enums whose values contain a white space in GraphQL

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, graphql, nestjs

My project is in nestjs/graphql. I have a similar enum type to the following:

```js
enum UserRoles {
    admin = 'admin',
    superAdmin = 'super admin'
}

registerEnumType(UserRoles, { name: 'UserRoles' })
```

In the database, user roles are stored as the values of this enum i.e. `'admin'` and `'super admin'`. However graphql takes enum elements from enum keys and has generated

```js
enum UserRoles {
    admin
    superAdmin
}
```

However, then I'm getting conflicts between `'superAdmin'` and `'super admin'`.

I tried rewriting my enum as

```js
enum UserRoles {
    admin = 'admin',
    'super admin' = 'super admin'
}
```

But then, as you can guess, graphql could not parse this and throwed an error while building.

How can I handle this kind of situations. What are the possible solutions except changing every document in the database from `'super admin'` to `'superAdmin'`.